# Program doesn't execute for loop until the end

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code to enter subjects' information where I put void function and array as an object. But not sure when I wanna loop it, it doesn't come until the end. Have a look at the code.

```
void calculateCGPA::getGPA() {
    cout << "Enter the the name of the subject: ";
    cin >> subjectName;
    cout << "Enter the credit hour:";
    cin >> credithour;
    cout << "Enter the grade: ";
    cin >> grade;
}

int main () {
    for (year=1; year<=4; year++) {
        for (sem=1; sem<=2; sem++) {
            cout << "Enter total subject you take in Year " << year << " Semester " << sem <<": ";
            cin >> totalSubjectSem;
            calculateCGPA ob[totalSubjectSem];
            for(int i = 1; i <= totalSubjectSem; i++) {
                cout << "Subject " << i << ": \n";
                ob[i].getGPA();
              }
        }
    }
    
return 0;   
}
```

[image]

Here's the error. You can see the compiler only shows until entering the subject name but credit hour and grade are omitted. What should I do?

Expected: It should everything in void function until 3 (since I put 3) and then start over again "Enter total subject you take in Year 1 sem 2" but it also omits that

Comment: I suggest that you repeat arrays and subscrips in C++.

Comment: @273K what do u mean? clarify more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note that in C++ 0 is the first element, and n-1 is the last element. By looping to n, you cause a buffer overflow, hence resulting an error.

A solution would be as follows

```cpp
void calculateCGPA::getGPA() {
    cout << "Enter the the name of the subject: ";
    cin >> subjectName;
    cout << "Enter the credit hour:";
    cin >> credithour;
    cout << "Enter the grade: ";
    cin >> grade;
}

int main () {
    for (year=0; year<4; year++) {
        for (sem=0; sem<2; sem++) {
            cout << "Enter total subject you take in Year " << year << " Semester " << sem <<": ";
            cin >> totalSubjectSem;
            calculateCGPA ob[totalSubjectSem];
            for(int i = 0; i < totalSubjectSem; i++) {
                cout << "Subject " << i << ": \n";
                ob[i].getGPA();
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> calculateCGPA ob[totalSubjectSem];

It's GCC extension called *Variable-length automatic arrays* and not valid C++ (because `totalSubjectSem` is not `const`). Use `std::vector<calculateCGPA>` instead.

> for(int i = 1; i <= totalSubjectSem; i++) {

Indices start from 0 and going to `array_length - 1`. On last iteration you reading out of array bounds and program is crashing.